# SQL Server : trigger error customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

For some reason my trigger isn't working. I'm trying to create a trigger that updates whenever a customer pays.

Here is the code:

```
Select * from customers
Select * from customerAudit

CREATE TRIGGER tr_customer_ForUpdate
ON customers
FOR UPDATE
AS  
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO customerAudit 
       SELECT
          'Customer with ID = ' + Cast (customersID as NVARCHAR(5)) + ' paid at ' + cast(Getdate() as NVARCHAR(20))
       FROM 
          updated;
END
```

`updated` has invalid object name and `customersID` has invalid column name. I'm very confused :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pseudo tables in a SQL Server trigger are called `Deleted` (for the old values of an `UPDATE`) and `Inserted` (for the new values, after the `UPDATE` - not `Updated`).

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO customerAudit (ColumnName)
   SELECT
      'Customer with ID = ' + Cast (customersID as NVARCHAR(5)) + ' paid at ' + cast(Getdate() as NVARCHAR(20))
   FROM 
      Inserted;
```